# Is it possible to reprogram an atMega328 chip inside of a pcb?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I have already soldered the atMega chip with instructions onto the perfboard, and I may need to make changes to it. Is it possible to reprogram it without taking it out of the PCB?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to program using an AVR programmer.

Yes, it's very likely you'll be able to do that. You need to connect the AVR programmer to the correct MCU pins (Sck, Si, So and Rst), including ground and vcc... as you would do with the chip by itself.

If you have any othe SPI device connected to the same pins, make sure it's not enabled - that might be as simple as having the device's CS pulled high.

The way you'll make the connection is up to you, you might need to use some clips, pogo pins or simply solder some wires to the MCU pins.

If you have other things connected to any of the MCU programming pins, you might need to disconnect, but that will vary case by case.

Cheers